# Page Controller Width (iPhone)

Tags: ios, iphone, uipagecontrol

I have a page controller with varying number of pages. The problem is, it is going fine when number of pages are less. But for 32 pages, it stretches out of view. Following is the code I have been using to fit it in screen:

```
self.pageControl.frame = CGRectMake(43, 440, self.view.frame.size.width, 36);
self.pageControl.center = CGPointMake(self.view.center.x, 440);
```

Since the page number won't exceed 32, I want to use page control. I think there must be some way to reduce the constant space between bullets to fit all bullets in.
Due to no reputation, I couldn't add screenshot.

Comment: 32 pages?? You should start using some other navigation mechanism rather than the page control... Back/forward Arrows and Page Number are an option.

Comment: Actually I have both Back/Forward buttons and pageControl too. For screen shot is on the following link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/wpw7bgy4h9aame2/Screen%20Shot%202014-02-04%20at%206.42.52%20PM.png

Comment: You can adjust the pageControl position as its currentPage changes

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use a page controller for that many pages.

It doesn't make sense. It would be like using a UIPickerView to select from a list of 500 items.

It might work but it isn't user friendly. You might be better coming up with a different way of displaying the current page.